# Perfect squares from odd numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

In JavaScript, is there a more efficient way of calculating perfect squares working from odd numbers than this (the last perfect square stored in the array `perfectSqrs` is console.logged):

```
let n = 999,
    oddNums = [],
    i;
for (i = 3; i < n; i += 1) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        oddNums.push(i);
    }
}
let oddLength = oddNums.length;
let perfectSqrs = [1],
    j = 0;
while (j < oddLength - 1) {
    perfectSqrs[j + 1] = perfectSqrs[j] + oddNums[j];
    j += 1;
}
console.log(perfectSqrs[perfectSqrs.length - 1]);
```

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: why do you think this code calculates perfect squares at all?

Comment: SO isn't a good place to ask for a code review. There's another site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lashane - Does it not? I was working from [a math.stackexchange.com question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639068/sum-of-odd-numbers-always-gives-a-perfect-square)

Comment: I can't even make sense of what this code is doing to begin with. Doesn't look like it has anything to do with perfect squares.

Comment: @cssimsek finally got it, very weird unclear logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just want to generate an array of perfect squares? Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
var squares = [1];
var numSquares = 100;

for (var i=3; i<numSquares*2; i+=2) {
  squares.push(squares[squares.length - 1] + i);
}

console.log(squares);
```

For people unclear about this algorithm, basically:

- 1
- 4 (1+3)
- 9 (1+3+5)
- 16 (1+3+5+7)
- 25 (1+3+5+7+9)

Perfect square is essentially the sum of odd numbers

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with JS more with algorithms and logic. You can totally avoid the first loop and also avoid storing (memory efficiency) odd numbers. Start your second loop with 1 and iterate by incrementing by 2 instead of 1 (1,3,5,7,...).